# How to do "nested" eager loading in Entity Framework?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

Scenario:

```
Employee:     EmployeeId   (PK)    DepartmentId_FK  (FK)   Name and other fields
Department:   DepartmentId (PK)    CompanyId_FK     (FK)   Name and other fields
Company:      CompanyId    (PK)                            Name and other fields
```

How can I build a linq query that can join the three tables and returns EmployeeName, DepartmentName and CompanyName?

the following syntax does not work because there is no Navigation Property names `Company` on `Employee.cs`.

```
var model = DataContext.Employee
                .Include("Employer")
                .Include("Company");
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to load nested Entity Framework objects efficiently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274281/how-to-load-nested-entity-framework-objects-efficiently)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
 var data = DataContext.Employees.Include("Department").Include("Department.Company");
```

But use this with caution as eager loading can hurt back if there is large amount of data.

Comment: You don't need the `Include("Department")`; that's implied by the `Include("Department.Company")`. See the remarks at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx